# npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY when npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nvm, nvm-windows

npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-KdCC7X8lzuKpwZqEZX4YQF9n7Dy00tPMWjV0p8ktwNjUIN5MOF+RWDzXUBBp/zJZyMreBxFwBfTwel0oCBzwNQ== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-KdCC7X8lzuKpwZqEZX4YQF9n7Dy00tPMWjV0p8ktwNjUIN5MOF+RWDzXUBBp/zJZyMreBxFwBfTwel0oCBzwNQ== but got sha512-VzAbE9fQ9JnIKrocjcJB2NgMuP3MU2SAGnurTEVL0Ox5/Bz+9s/MSZ4XHfXkh52YeNjCPc5U169VtIV8v/x29Q==. (327680 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

tried steps:

- npm cache clean --force
- removed node modules and package-lock and npm install
- uninstall the node and and install latest node
- uninstall nvm and reinstall the latest

currently using node version: 10.24.0

currently using NVM version: 1.1.9

**current problem:**

- Try to npm install,but it thrown error of npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY.
- This issue arise after switch the node version 10.24.0 to 16.17.0
  using nvm

**expect:**

please share the details with cause